Redirect Directly to OAuth Login in NextAuth.js Without Showing Sign-In Page
I am using NextAuth.js (Auth.js) in my Next.js 14 application with an OIDC provider for authentication.
I have implemented my own Oauth provider. I have implemented the following logic in my layout.tsx to restrict users from accessing the application without logging in:
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const loggedIn = await auth();
  if (!loggedIn) redirect('/api/auth/signin');
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {/* layout content */}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

This successfully redirects to the sign-in page, but wanted to bypass the sign-in button selection and redirect users directly to the OAuth login page.
Here’s my OIDC provider setup:
export default function OwnIdentityProvider(options: any): Provider {
    return {
        id: "admin-spa",
        name: "Online Admin",
        type: "oidc",
        issuer: `${process.env.AUTH_IDENTITY_URL}/`,
        authorization: {
            url: `${process.env.AUTH_IDENTITY_URL}/connect/authorize`,
            params: {
                responseType: 'id_token',
                scope: 'openid profile email api1',
            },
        },
        // token, userinfo, etc.
    }
}

Is there a way to skip the sign-in selection page and redirect directly to the OAuth login page when a user is not logged in?
I get this page, when: redirect('/api/auth/signin');

Which i want to bypass and directly go to the login page.
and also what is the best approach to check if the user is logged in or not when trying to browse the application using the root url?
